# Iterate over an object in es6

Tags: ecmascript-6

This works fine for me:

```
const iterable = [1, 2, 3];

for (const value of iterable) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

However this does not work:

```
const iterable = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30};

for (const value of iterable) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(iterable[value]);
}
```

Instead giving me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: iterable[Symbol.iterator] is not a function(…)
```

How should I be doing this?

This is what I do now:

```
for(const value in iterable){
    if (iterable.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(iterable[value]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `for … in`? And no, the first example shouldn't "work" either.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. Just use a `for…in` loop. You don't need the `.hasOwnProperty` check, btw.

Answer (score 21):

`for..of` only works for [iterable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable). You could implement an iterator like this:

```
const iterable = {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      i: 1,
      next() {
        if (this.i <= 3) {
          return { value: 10 * this.i++, done: false };
        }
        return { value: undefined, done: true };
      }
    };
  }
};

for (const value of iterable2) {
    console.log(value);
} // 10, 20, 30
```

To iterate over plain objects, other than `for...in` which I think is fine, you could use `Object.keys`:

```
const iterable = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30};
Object.keys( iterable ).forEach( key => {
    console.log( iterable[key] );
});  // 10, 20, 30
```

BTW your first example throws a syntax error, maybe you meant `const iterable = [1,2,3]`? Then it would work since Arrays are iterable objects.

Comment: i feel top code is 5x less readable

Comment: In the second example, if you don't care about `iterable`'s keys (1, 2, 3) but only its values (10, 20, 30), you can write `Object.values(iterable).forEach(value => console.log(value));`

Comment: @robinmetral good point. I think at the time of writing this answer `Object.values` hasn't been as widely supported as it is now.

Comment: @pawel yes, `Object.values()` is somewhat new. Just mentioning it so that readers as of today will know there'y another way :)